# 3D lines intersection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry

I have line direction using x,y,z

and two points A, B , I used line segment using B- A

how to get the intersection point between them

Best regards

Comment: convert your lines into systems of linear equations, then combine them and solve the resulting system

Comment: what if the lines do not intersect at all? This is very likely situation with 1D lines in 3D.

Comment: Does the first line go through the origin, as you only have a direction?

Comment: If you try and state the problem properly, you might actually solve it by yourself easily.

Answer (score 8):

**Sytem of equations:**

The parametrice equation of a line with direction (a,b,c) and one point X(x1,x2,x3) is :

```
D1:(x, y, z) = (x1, y1, z1) + t1(a, b, c)
```

The parametrice equation of a line with 2 points A and B is :

```
 D2:(x, y, z) = (xa, ya, za) + t2(xb-xa, yb-ya, zb-za)
```

you just need to equalize D1 and D2 to get the result finding the parameter t1 and t2 that will work. (3 equations with 2 unknown)

If there is no solution there is no intersection.

**Intersection with the segment only:**

Now let M be you result you just need to verify :

```
t2 in [0,1] 

 or  0<AM.AB<||AB||^2 (M is in the segment AB)
```

**remark:**

If the representation of your line are from cartesian equations (intersection of plans) than the problem is the same but with 4 equations an 3 unknown

**Example:**

```
A (1,1,1)
B (0,0,0)
D2:(x,y,z)=(1-t2,1-t2,1-t2)

(a,b,c)=(1.-1.1)
(x1,y1,z1)=(1,0,1)
D1:(x,y,z)=(t1+1,-t1,1+t1)
```

(D1 and D2 are 2 diagonals of the cube of side =1 placed on 0,0,0)

let M(x,y,z) be the intersection D1, D2

we find t1 and t2 that equalize the above equation: D1 and D2

we get easily **t1=-1/2 and t2=1/2**

moreover t2 is in [0,1] so the resulting intersection is in [A,B]

**M(1/2,1/2,1/2) =D1(t1)=D2(t2) is the solution**

Comment: You know you've written the equation of a plane in 3D, as there are infinitely many n orthogonal to AB.

Comment: Aha sorry, yep I will correct it. parametric equation of a line is: (x, y, z) = (x1, y1, z1,) + t(a, b, c) where a,b,c is the directional vector

Comment: could u give me more details, I couldn't understand that, I have the line direction as vector , x , y, z componenet

Comment: @AMH , ok corrected, the idea is the same. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: @Ricky Seems correct now. By the way, for the segment check you can also test if t2 is in [0,1].

Comment: excuse me what do u mean by M, if there's a numerical example will be great